# How to remove list of list at specific index

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to figure out how to delete an entire list at a specific index if the first element on the inside list meets a certain condition. Below I've shown an example of what I want done but when I run the code I'm getting a list index out of range error in python. If the list[i][0] meets a certain condition I want that entire list delete from the overall list.

```py
list = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]

for i in range(0, len(list)):
  if list[i][0] == 0:
    del list[i]

return list
```

Below I've shown a picture of what happens when I run the sample code in IDLE, the first time I run the loop it gives an error but the second time I run the code (copy and pasted both times) it doesn't and it does what I'm asking.

[Weird Python Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgpCy.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please edit your question to add also the Python Error instead of a link to an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting an element from the middle of a list moves everything down, breaking indexing. You need to either remove elements from the end:

```
for i in range(len(lst)-1, -1, -1):
    if lst[i][0] == 0:
        del lst[i]
```

or build a new list and assign it back to the variable, which would also be much more efficient:

```
lst = [x for x in lst if x[0] != 0]
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense -- I've faced this problem before but I forgot for loops set range once. Thank you for your help, I'll accept your answer in a minute when I can!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this, and 'list' is not a good variable name since it's already a builtin function:

```
my_list = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
my_list = [l for l in list if l[0] != 0]
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's not a good idea to remove elements from list while iterating through it like that because the first time you remove an element the list will no longer be the same length.

1) Create completely new list which will contain elements you want to keep:

`listname = [element for element in listname if element[0] != 0]`

2) Modify the list you already have (you can do this since lists are mutable):

`listname[:] = [element for element in listname if element[0] != 0]`

I would recommend using the second approach in case you have references to the same list somewhere else in you program.

Also try not to name your variables list, it's really not a good practice and it probably is not possible since it's keyword.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not *ever* call your variables `list`.

Second, a `while` loop may be a slightly better solution:

```
stop = range(len(mylist))
i = 0
while i < stop: 
  if mylist[i][0] == 0:
    del mylist[i]
    stop -= 1
  else:
    i += 1
```

Third, a list comprehension is event better:

```
[item for item in mylist if item[0] != 0]
```

Comment: I never do, I was just using it in the example code in hopes to make it more readable! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's always bad idea to remove elements from a container while you are iterating over it.

A better approach would be to instead of removing bad elements from the list, copy good ones to a new list:

```
original = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
new_list = []

for l in original:
  if list[0] != 0:
    new_list.append(l)

return new_list
```

And by the way, "list" is a python keyword and can't be used as variable name.

Or better, use the built-in filter function:

```
return filter(lambda l : l[0] != 0, original)
```